# Автоматический вывод метки "Новинка" на товаре

Tags: php

Нужно вывести метку "Новинка", если с момента добавления товара в базу (тип ячейки `date`) прошло, например, менее 30 дней и убрать, если более. То есть сравнить текущую дату с датой добавления товара в базу.

Comment: а что не получается?

Comment: Александр, не знаю, как сравнить даты. Впервые с этим типом работаю в таком ключе, до этого только выводил  и всё.

Comment: select to_days(now())-to_days(dt) from table разница в днях даты из базы и текущей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто, как один из возможных вариантов...

Получаете текущую дату и дату добавления товара (из БД) и находите разность между ними (например, в днях). Если эта разность меньше определённой величины (например, товар добавлен не ранее чем неделю назад), выводите пометку "Новинка".

Как-то так...

Comment: Даты - это же не простые числа, которые можно сравнить простым вычитанием, например,  таким: `$date1 = getdate();
$date2 = $item['item_date'];
$date_diff = $date1 - $date2;
echo $date_diff;`

Comment: @Torawhite, даты можно прекрасно сравнивать простым вычитанием ([ссылка на **рабочий** пример](http://expange.ru/e/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82_%28PHP%29)). В остальном, я всего лишь на словах описал общий принцип. Конкретная реализация может быть произвольной (включая получение из БД уже "готовой" разности дат).

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался!

Answer (score 1):

Справочное руководство по MySQL[Функции даты и времени](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Date_and_time_functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего вместе с запросом вытаскивать из базы кол-во дней от сегодня.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(), [date-fld])
```

Ну а если Вам нужно именно средствами `php` (других тэгов в вопросе нет), то можно воспользоваться функцией `date_diff()` (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date-diff.php)